# Deleting Attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: java, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to figure out the best way to delete an attribute from an item in Dynamo DB.  Below is what I tried, but I get an exception saying that DELETE is not a supported for either type N or S.

> Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonDynamoDB, AWS Request ID: 09MRO4PVTJ8IK6OHLKSM551REJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, AWS Error Code: ValidationException, AWS Error Message: One or more parameter values were invalid: Action DELETE is not supported for the type N
>     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
>     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:284)
>     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:169)
>     at >com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:675)
>     at >com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:371)

```
Key pk = new Key(new AttributeValue().withN(Long.toString(123)));
AttributeValueUpdate avu = new AttributeValueUpdate(new AttributeValue().withN("555"), "DELETE");
Map<String, AttributeValueUpdate> m = new HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate>();
m.put(String.valueOf(555), avu);
UpdateItemRequest uir = new UpdateItemRequest("users", pk, m);
dynamoDB.updateItem(uir);
```

One point of confusion is why the attribute value matters for a deletion.  I really want to delete an attribute name and any associated values, but couldn't find the appropriate way to do that in the SDK.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the actual exception

Comment: @Layble: Glad you managed to resolve this yourself - could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it? Following up to your own question is perfectly reasonable and desired, as long as it has been a real open question in the first place. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could have sworn I already tried this but by replacing the AttributeValue with a null value it works:

```
Key pk = new Key(new AttributeValue().withN(Long.toString(123)));
AttributeValueUpdate avu = new AttributeValueUpdate(null, "DELETE");
Map<String, AttributeValueUpdate> m = new HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate>();
m.put(String.valueOf(555), avu);
UpdateItemRequest uir = new UpdateItemRequest("users", pk, m);
dynamoDB.updateItem(uir);
```

For Kotlin:

```
dynamoDB.updateItem( UpdateItemRequest(
    "users", 
    Key(AttributeValue().withN(123L.toString()), 
    mapOf("555" to AttributeValueUpdate(null, "DELETE"))
))
```

Answer (score 9):

This also works.

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("users");
table.updateItem(
    new PrimaryKey("<MY HASH KEY NAME>", <MY HASH VALUE>), 
    new AttributeUpdate("columnToRemove").delete()
);
```

or [you can even use Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) in an Item Update.

> REMOVE - Removes one or more attributes from an item.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an Attribute from Dynamo DB while Updating an item of the table

```
 UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest =new UpdateItemRequest().withTableName(tableName).withKey(key);
 updateItemRequest.addAttributeUpdatesEntry("privileges",new AttributeValueUpdate()
          .withAction(AttributeAction.DELETE));

updateItemRequest.addAttributeUpdatesEntry("description", new AttributeValueUpdate()
          .withValue(new AttributeValue().withS("description")));
```

In above Example, First I removed `privileges` from Item and then updated  `description` in Item.