# Deleting Item Within Item in DynamoDB with Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

There is [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html) given by AWS on how to delete an item within a table.  However, I'm not trying to delete the entire item; I'm only trying to delete a few rows within the item.

Let's say I have this item in a DynamoDB table (the same example from the documentation).

```
{
   year: 2015,
   title: "The Big New Movie",
   info: {
           plot: "Everything happens all at once.",
           rating: 5.5,
           actors: ["Larry", "Moe", "Curly"]
   }
}
```

I understand the guidance the documentation is giving on deleting items in a table, but let's say don't want to delete this entire item; I only want to delete  that "title" portion.

Is this something possible?  Is the only way really to just delete the entire item and create another item with the fields I want?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's not deleting an item. What you are removing isn't a DynamoDB item, it's an attribute on a DynamoDB item.

Comment: In the example table you pointed to, the `title` attribute is actually part of the item's key so you would not be able to delete that specific attribute. For other, non-key attributes then yes you can, e.g. by using a REMOVE update expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me more like updating than deleting, this might help:
[Deleting Attribute in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142074/deleting-attribute-in-dynamodb)